# Proper way to handle issue when porting 32 to 64 bit. Conversion from DT1 to DT2 of greater size

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit, porting

So I am trying to port 32 bit to 64 bit.

I have turned on the VS2008 flag for detecting problems with 64 bit.

I am trying following:

```
char * pList = (char *)uiTmp);
```

warning C4312: 'type cast' : conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'char *' of greater size

Disregard the code itself. This is also true for any pointer, because 64 bit pointer is greater than 32 bit unsigned int or int for that purpose.

Given that you have to cast smaller type to greater how would you go about doing it so it correctly on both 32/64 bit systems

Comment: I guess the obvious question is: why are you casting an integer to a pointer?

Comment: What you're asking basically seems to come down to "how can I write 64 bits of data into a 32-bit variable". The answer may shock and surprise you, but **it is not possible**. You have to write it into a pointer-sized integer type if you want to avoid losing data.

Comment: At first I thought jalf had it back to front, but I see what he means now.  For `pList` to hold a meaningful pointer value after the assignment (i.e. assuming we want to access the pointed-to value later on), it must be assigned a 64-bit value, not a 32-bit value such as `uiTmp`. So yes, `uiTmp`'s type must be changed to a 64-bit integer type.

Comment: you are casting 32 bit type to 64 bit so its more than enough place to store it jalf.

i am not talking about case when you try storing pointer into int (64 to store at 32 bit of course can't work)

Comment: But obviously(?) if you're getting a pointer out of the int, you had to put it there in the first place, which is the real problem.

Comment: @Mark B - I agree. However, sometimes you are presented with an interface or API that requires it. For instance, there are some system calls that take in a pointer as far as the compiler is concerned, but in some cases (based on the values of other parameters) actually interpret that parameter as an integer. Ugly, but old C APIs are full of stuff like that.

Comment: @T.E.D. Unless you can guarantee that your code won't be relocated into high memory addresses, you can't use those C libraries then.

Comment: @Mark B : I agree. Its just that a lot of people got into the habit of using `void *` to mean "some paramater of indeterminate (or varying) type". In some situations, it might legitimately supposed to be a 4-byte integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a warning you can ignore, it will bomb in 64-bit code.  An unsigned int cannot store a pointer.  There's no magic cast that will make this work.

Review your code and rethink storing pointer values in an unsigned int.  It should probably be a void*.  If you `#include <windows.h>` then you can use UINT_PTR.

Comment: On any environment having `stdint.h` (which is standard in C99, though sadly not supported by MSVC++), use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`. These are defined to be integer types wide enough to hold a pointer.

Comment: I'm curious why this got accepted, given that it answers a totally different question. The problem was that he was trying to store an unsigned int into a pointer, not the other way around. Physically, it should fit just fine with 32 bits to spare.

Comment: This answer was obviously assuming that uiTmp was supposed to contain a pointer value, assigned somewhere else. Another interpretation would make little sense.  Well, to me and the OP anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. In my case the code was trying to generate a random HANDLE using rand() which returns a 32-bit value. (*Why* did it want a random handle value? Don't ask...)

What I found works to appease the compiler was the following:

```
char * pList = (char *)(0) + uiTmp;
```

This should work OK if your system uses 32-bit or 64-bit pointers. Of course you might not want to be using 32-bit integers on a 64-bit platform, depending on what exactly your code is doing.

Comment: I only need it because the pointer is printed as hexa (by some function). Thanks (for answering the question)!

Answer (score 2):

The `Basetsd.h` header features [various functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/the-new-data-types) for converting between pointers and integers. In particular, the function `UIntToPtr` might be what you want:

```
char * pList = UIntToPtr(uiTmp);
```

This will zero-extend the given unsigned int value, i.e. in 64bit builds, the upper 32bit of the `pList` pointer will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Main points to watch out for when moving from 32 to 64 bit platform:

- `sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*)` anymore. Audit all occurrences of casting integer to pointer and back.
- Structure alignment and sizes change. For example the following is packed into 8 bytes on 32 bit, but has a hole in the middle and takes 16 bytes on 64 bit:

```
    struct list
    {
        int          val_;
        struct list* next_;
    };
```

- Implicit assumptions for IPC and network communications will bite you.

One specific issue I came across several times was that on 32-bit Linux repeated calls to [`vprintf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/vfprintf) without re-initializing [`va_list`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg) with `va_end/va_start` silently works (while being undefined behavior), but loudly bombs on 64-bit due to different calling convention.